# How do I clean data grouped by state/months in R?

Tags: r, data-analysis, data-cleaning

I have a dataset with 16 variables and a lot of obs.

There are a lot of NA's in each variable. The question is related to 2+1* variable:
2 - "state" and "month"
1* - temperature or wind velocity, etc..

What I want to do is:
1. get the median by state and then by month (without NA )

```
group_by(state, month)
```

2. Use this median to replace the NA's on each varible by month and state.

Comment: See the instructions at the top of the [tag:r] tag page for posting.  In particular, provide a small dataset possibly cut down from the one you have or artificial data showing it using `dput` in your post and show the code that you have tried.

Comment: You can use the [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/magic-reprex.html) package to create a reproducible example. See also [Help me Help you](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace `NA` values in all columns with it's median for each `state` and `month`, you can use `dplyr` as :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(state, month) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-group_cols()), ~replace(., is.na(.), median(., na.rm = TRUE)))
```